# Type '(control: AbstractControl) => Observable<unknown>' is not assignable to type 'AsyncValidatorFn'

Tags: angular, angular12

I am trying to get working an async email validator and this code is from a tutorial but I think the versions changed and it complains and honestly I don't understand this error.

```
validateEmailNotTaken(): AsyncValidatorFn {
return control => {
  return timer(500).pipe(
    switchMap(() => {
      if (!control.value) {
        return of(null);
      }
      return this.accountService.checkEmailExists(control.value).pipe(
        map(res => {
          return res ? { emailExists: true } : null;
        })
      );
    })
  );
};
```

error:

```
Type '(control: AbstractControl) => Observable<unknown>' is not assignable to type 
 'AsyncValidatorFn'.
  Type 'Observable<unknown>' is not assignable to type 'Promise<ValidationErrors | null> | Observable<ValidationErrors | null>'.
    Type 'Observable<unknown>' is not assignable to type 'Observable<ValidationErrors | null>'.
      Type 'unknown' is not assignable to type 'ValidationErrors | null'.
```

First of all can someone explain me how to read this error?

So I am assuming all errors are related to first return but because I didn't specified a type in `switchMap` or at the end it throws this error and I don't know what types it needs.

Thank you

Edit: So I figured out that this error comes from the empty paramter switchMap but I don't know what to provide inside for a parameter

Edit2: If I remove the last return then I get a different error inside the switchMap block:

```
Argument of type '() => Observable<null> | undefined' is not assignable to parameter of type '(value: 0, index: number) => ObservableInput<any>'.
  Type 'Observable<null> | undefined' is not assignable to type 'ObservableInput<any>'.
    Type 'undefined' is not assignable to type 'ObservableInput<any>'.
```

Edit3: per comment

```
  email: new FormControl('', [
    Validators.required,
    Validators.pattern('^[\\w-\\.]+@([\\w-]+\\.)+[\\w-]{2,4}$'),
  ], [this.validateEmailNotTaken()]),
```

Comment: Are you sure you’re actually using this validator inside the async validator array on the control?

Comment: edited my post, you mean if I am using it in the second array of validators?

Comment: Indeed what I meant. So that looks good. I wonder if the timer does something unexpected type wise. Why do you need it in the first place?

Comment: Well I am trying to learn `"difficult"` things I haven't tried so far with Angular, so I don't really know what exactly I am doing. In tutorial said `allow us to debounce the request and add some delay`. But I think I know why is returned at the highest level, in this tutorial he has a component just for inputs and errors, maybe thats why he is returning like this and I didn't followed that part.

Comment: Makes sense. You’re probablt looking for the debounceTime operator for that..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try adding stricter typing - it may just be that the types aren't explicit enough

```js
validateEmailNotTaken(): AsyncValidatorFn {
   return (control: AbstractControl): Observable<ValidationErrors | null> => {
     ...
```

Comment: I got now `Type 'Observable<unknown>' is not assignable to type 'Observable<ValidationErrors | null>'.
  Type 'unknown' is not assignable to type 'ValidationErrors | null'.`

Comment: I forgot to `return` the call in the `checkEmailExists`. Its funny because I tried something similar to your solution since first line of the error is obvious but then I got this second error, and I was sure I `return` something that isn't unknown and giving a type in map like `any` still didn't worked, then I reverted everything and asked the question, I was so close but yet so far because I was confused, I should have been sticking with first line of the error and debug from there.